# Bubble chart and rowchart are not sync, dc.js

Tags: reduce, dc.js

There is a simple bubble chart (dimension by level1, level2) and row chart(dimension by level_1)
see 
https://codepen.io/shakraz/pen/dyYXxJy

```
    var houseDim = ndx.dimension(d=>[d.district, d.name, d.price, d.flat_rate, d.building_rate]); 
var districtDim = ndx.dimension(d=>[d.district])
```

When i click on row chart i expect to see only filtered bubbles, right? But it doesn't work.
But it works vice versa, clicking on bubble filters rowchart, why is that?
For sure it somehow related with **reduce** function.
Thank you for any advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a better practice to keep any *measures* in the `value` part of the crossfilter group, and leave only the *index* in the `key`.

Crossfilter will bin the groups according to the group and dimension key functions. Your instinct was correct that you should be able to use `d.name` because you want a bubble per row of your data, and `d.name` is a unique key.

```
var houseDim = ndx.dimension(d=>d.name);
```

Here is one simple way to copy each row into a group value:

```
var houseGroup=houseDim.group().reduce(
  (p, d) => ({...p, ...d, count: (d.count || 0) + 1}), // add
  (p, d) => ({...p, count: p.count - 1}), // remove
  ()  => {} // init
);
```

When adding a row, it will copy the data from the row, adding a field called `count`. Since the keys are unique, the count will be either 1 or 0, depending whether the row is filtered in or out.

Now we can use descriptive field names instead of indexing arrays in the code:

```
.keyAccessor(function (p) {
  return p.value.flat_rate;
})

.valueAccessor(function (p) {
  return p.value.building_rate;
})
// ...
.title(function (p) {
   return p.key + "\n"
   + "Индекс квартиры: " + p.value.flat_rate + "\n"
   + "Индекс дома: " + p.value.building_rate + " \n"
   + "Район: " + p.value.district + "\n"
   + "Цена: " + p.value.price
})
```

We also need to visually encode being excluded, by using `d.value.count` in some of  the accessors. I like to send both radius and opacity to zero, but leaving the radius and only using opacity has a calm effect too.

```
.radiusValueAccessor(function (p) {
  console.log('radius', p)
  return p.value.count * priceScale(p.value.price);
})
// .colors(colorScale)
// .colorAccessor(function(p) {return p.value.district})
.colorCalculator(p => p.value.count ? colorScale(p.value.district) : 'rgba(0,0,0,0)')
```

The bubble chart doesn't expose opacity in its public api, but this `colorCalculator` trick sends opacity to zero when `count` is 0, and invokes the ordinary `colorScale` on the value otherwise.

I also had to point to correct dc.css URL in order to get selection behavior to work.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/dc/dist/style/dc.css">
```

[Working fork of your codepen](https://codepen.io/gordonwoodhull/pen/vYNXzEw)